# Symfony 5 Demo Routing Issue

Tags: symfony, routes, public

I am running Symfony 5, with Apache2 WebServer.
Routing works fine to my main page in the /public directory. But in order to route to other configured routes in my routes (.yaml) file

I need to add  /index.php/ in the URL for the route to work.
for example: Index Page
ROUTE = /
URL =>  http//example.com/
Works Fine

```
ROUTE = /Lucky_Number 
URL => http://example.com/lucky   ==> Requested Page not found.
URL I have to type  => http://example.com/index.php/lucky    ==> Works Fine
```

This gives me access to the page I need, but I can't figure out why I have to prefix all my routes in        the URL with /index.php/...

I did googling to see if anyone had a similar issue, but i couldn't find any hits with my issue. I tried modifying my routes but reverted back as I am working on the Symfony Demo, I don't suspect this is the problem.
I also modified the site home directory in Apache from /public to the site root and reverted back.
I installed and removed with Composer Apache-Pack.

Comment: `apache-pack` should have done the trick. Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction,  i installed the apache-pack, read the documents regarding mod_rewrite and the information from Symfony (Apache with mod_php/PHP-CGI) my site navigation is working fine.